# Creating callback function in ATL COM object and use in JScript

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, com, jscript

I have created COM object using using `Visual c++` ATL project with one function `tst2` that passes int in sigle parameter.

I can all it easily from JScript:

```
c= new ActiveXObject("myC2.1");
c.tst2(1);
```

But now I need to create and use callback function in my `COM` and use in `JScript`. I suppose `JScript` side will look like:

```
c.onHello = function() {
    WScript.Echo("onHello");
};
```

But how to create such function in `COM`? I suppose I need to add property `onHello` , but which property type I need to select?

[image]

UPD.

According to [dscription](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/invoking-javascript-callbacks-using-com/184416311) now I have object with callback fucntion `function Func()` that has no parameters.

In JScript:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>ATL 3.0 test page for object ScriptCallback</TITLE>
    <SCRIPT>
// The callback function
//
function Func()
{
    // Alert on activation and test context
    alert(this.Callback.toString());
}

// Connect the script callback
// Wait until page (and the control) are fully loaded
//
function Loaded()
{
    ScriptCallback.Callback = Func;
}
window.onload = Loaded;
    </SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <OBJECT ID="ScriptCallback" 
        CLASSID="CLSID:986FB4FE-75D8-4D1C-9D9C-A755F15C2C8C"
        HEIGHT=1 WIDTH=1>
    </OBJECT>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

COM C++ code:

```
STDMETHODIMP CScriptCallback::get_Callback(VARIANT* pVal)
{
    // Return copy of current value
    return VariantCopy(pVal, &m_vCallback);
}

STDMETHODIMP CScriptCallback::put_Callback(VARIANT newVal)
{
    // Verify correct argument type
    if ( newVal.vt != VT_NULL && newVal.vt != VT_DISPATCH )
        return E_INVALIDARG;

    // Copy the reference value
    HRESULT hResult = m_vCallback.Copy(&newVal);
    if ( FAILED(hResult) )
        return hResult;

    // If set to null then we are done
    if ( m_vCallback.vt == VT_NULL )
        return S_FALSE;

    // If callback provided invoke it
    DISPID dispidThis = DISPID_THIS;
    CComVariant vThis(static_cast<IDispatch*>(this));
    DISPPARAMS params = { &vThis, &dispidThis, 1, 1};
    CComVariant vResult;
    m_vCallback.pdispVal->Invoke(DISPID_VALUE, IID_NULL, 
                                 LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_METHOD,
                                 &params, &vResult,
                                 NULL, NULL);
    return S_OK;
}
```

This works fine.

But how to deal if I need callback function that has string parameter passed to JScript ? Something like fucntion

```
function Func(string)
{

}
```

Comment: Property type is `IDispatch*` or `VARIANT` which will be holding `IDispatch*` value, Look up (e.g. [here](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/i-n/ieprogram/article.php/c4399/JavaScript-Calls-from-C.htm), or perhaps even better [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/invoking-javascript-callbacks-using-com/184416311)) on how to do the actual call (using `IDispatch::Invoke`).

Comment: This works fine, but how to deal if I need callback f-ion with parameter? Mor edetails in question body

Comment: `DISPPARAMS` could take additional arguments.